# PHP : INSERT PDO Query array as binding value

Tags: php, pdo

How to use `PDO` `Query` `array` with `Bindvalue` in this way ?
I get error

```
$productadd_query_array = array(
        "query" => "INSERT INTO vn_product (title) VALUES (:title)",
        "query_variables" => "bindValue(':title', '1')"
    );

$product_add = vn_db_query_select( $productadd_query_array );
```

Function vn_db_query_select:

```
function vn_db_query_select($array = null){

        if ( is_null( $array ) || !defined( 'MYSQL_USER' ) || !defined( 'MYSQL_PASSWORD' ) || !defined( 'MYSQL_HOST' ) || !defined( 'MYSQL_DATABASE' ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( !isset( $array["query"] ) || is_null( $array["query"] ) || strlen( $array["query"] ) < 11 ) {
            return false;
        }

        $pdo = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE.";charset=utf8", // DSN
            MYSQL_USER, // Username
            MYSQL_PASSWORD // Password
            //$pdoOptions // Options
        );

        $userInfo = $pdo->prepare($array["query"]); 

        if ( is_array( $array["query_variables"] ) ) {
            foreach ($array["query_variables"] as $var_name => $var_value) {
                $userInfo->bindValue(":".$var_name, $var_value);
            }
        }

        $userInfo->execute();
        $user = $userInfo->fetchAll();

        $pdo = null;

        return $user;
    }
```

Comment: Where does `vn_db_query_select()` come from?

Comment: @NigelRen thats array name i wanted to spilit select query arrays to other , i need to findout the way for bindingValue

Comment: Probably you need [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert#multiple)

Comment: Yes i know that but i want to use in 'query_variables' way @YourCommonSense

Comment: Sorry we have no idea what you mean

Comment: @YourCommonSense updated it

Comment: Whatever vn_db_query_select stuff **is not PDO**. You have to ask someone who wrote it.

Comment: You probably need to change the way you're doing query_variables. Instead of passing in `bindValue(':title', '1')`, pass in `[':title'=>'1']`, and then parse that for bindValue. The way you're doing it now looks like you're attempting to passing the function call in `vn_db_query_select`. But we'd need to see the code for `vn_db_query_select` to verify.

Comment: @aynber i added the function

Comment: @NigelRen i added the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code for `query_variables` here:

```
if ( is_array( $array["query_variables"] ) ) {
      foreach ($array["query_variables"] as $var_name => $var_value) {
           $userInfo->bindValue(":".$var_name, $var_value);
    }
}
```

It's expecting an array of keys=>values. So you need to pass it in like this:

```
"query_variables" => ['title'=> '1']
```

Or for older versions of PHP:

```
"query_variables" => array('title'=>'1')
```